# ¿Cómo mandar a llamar un archivo FXML desde la clase principal si se encuentran en distintos paquetes?

Tags: java, mvc, javafx

tengo el siguiente problema.
He intentado hacer la llamada de mi interfaz principal desde la clase main, en JavaFx, como se muestra a continuación. Pero he tenido el problema que me manda una Exception, ¿Me podrían ayudar para saber cual es mi error?, a mi parecer puede ser en la parte en como mando llamar el archivo fxml, pero he investigado e intentado algunos métodos pero todos me arrojan la misma Excpetion.

```
package com.testingdevops.elisium;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Elisium extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/ElisiumMainView.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("ELISIUM");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Teniendo como gerarquia de archivos en MVC como se muestra la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la ejecuto me aparece la siguiente Exception:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: la excepción es que no encuentra las librerías de javafx . o no están , o no estan declaradas en `module-info.java` . Debería añadir el contenido de module-info.java a su post

Comment: Muchas gracias, si ya logre agregar el contenido necesario al archivo module-info.java.